# Relative paths in xampp don't work

Tags: php, apache, path, xampp, relative-path

I'm running xampp and I have a simple site structure:

--> C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\pub\index.php

--> C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\other.php

in index.php I have

```
<?php require("../other.php"); ?>
```

When I navigate to index.php I see the following error:

> Warning: require(../other.php): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\pub\index.php on line 2
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '../other.php'
>   (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\pub\index.php on line 2

Doesn't "../" take me back to the previous directory? It works fine if I run the code online but not locally

** I'm more interested in why it doesn't work locally rather than a solution, as the problem is related to a project where I would have to change **alot** of paths manually just to get it to work locally

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
<?php require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/other.php"); ?>
```

Comment: when I echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] I get C:/xampp/htdocs... looks like I need to change the root. Is there any reason why relatives wont work though? Isn't it just relative to the file calling the require?

Answer (score 0):

This will definitely work.

```
<?php require(  realpath('/../'. basename(__FILE__)) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR  "other.php"); ?>
```

OR

```
<?php require( realpath('/../'. __DIR__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR  "other.php"); ?>
```

here
`basename(__FILE__)` and `__DIR__` belong to current directory.